# Redefinition problem with \maketitle from KOMA class (with optional argument)

Tags: macros, titles, koma-script, optional-arguments

I try to redefine the `\maketitle` command as shown below.

If I use an optional argument in the redefinition I get the `TeX capacity exceeded` error.

Any suggestion why?

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}

\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle

\renewcommand{\maketitle}[1][]{%
  \oldmaketitle
  \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of messing around with maketitle, I'd rather use the titlepage environment to design it!

Comment: Yes, but it is for supporting different maketitle versions in a package that adds a custom background style ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\let` with commands with optional arguments (and in the KOMA classes `\maketitle` is defined with one optional argument) can produce undesired effects: you can use `\LetLtxMacro` from the [`letltxmacro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) package instead:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}

\LetLtxMacro\oldmaketitle\maketitle

\renewcommand{\maketitle}[1][]{%
  \oldmaketitle
  \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Your example code doesn't show the usage of the optional argument.

Answer (score 5):

The `\maketitle` command in `scrreprt` has an optional argument, so redefining it with `\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle` and `\renewcommand\maketitle` exposes you to a very big problem, which is well described in the documentation of `letltxmacro`.

If all you need is to add something at the end of what `\maketitle` is doing, then a safe way is to use `xpatch` (or `regexpatch`):

```
\usepackage{xpatch} % or \usepackage{regexpatch}
\xapptocmd{\maketitle}{\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}{}{}
```

However this *won't* add a rule below the date. The reason is that with the default options `\maketitle` prints a page by itself and the rule will go on the next page; if `titlepage=false` is specified in the options, then the `\@maketitle` internal command is used.

So, in order to get a rule below the date, a better trick is to patch the commands and add the rule exactly after the printing of the date, which is done by `\@date`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xpatch} % or \usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
%% the following patch is for the `titlepage=true` option
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\@date}{\@date\par\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}{}{}
%% the following patch is for the `titlepage=false` option
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@date}{\@date\par\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]